# C# - When and how to initialize a context that will be used for the whole app lifetime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, singleton

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application that uses Azure Media Services for storing and displaying videos.

I connect to Azure using a context of type **CloudMediaContext**.

Since there is only one connection to the cloud, I need the same instance of this class throughout the whole application lifetime.

The code that creates the context is similar to this one:

```
private void InitializeMediaContext() {
    var tokenCredentials = new AzureAdTokenCredentials("<Email>",
                         new AzureAdClientSymmetricKey("<ClientID>", "<ClientKey>"),
                         AzureEnvironments.AzureCloudEnvironment);

    var tokenProvider = new AzureAdTokenProvider(tokenCredentials);

    if (_context == null)
    {
        CloudMediaContext context = new CloudMediaContext(
            new Uri("https://COMP.restv2.westeurope.media.azure.net/api/"), tokenProvider);
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

**Question:**

How do I create only one instance of `CloudMediaContext` and have access to it for the whole lifetime of the application? This instance should be created when the application starts.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a static class and put any properties there. The static class instance will be shared across all requests.

If there is any initialization, however; you need to be thread-aware, and use a lock for any one-time initialization.